Why can't I color the brackets and parenthesis, etc. in VScode theme extension coding?
Since I couldn't find the perfect theme for myself, I decided to make one.
I was able to modify everything to my liking, but nothing seemed to work, even chatgpt couldn't help me. My code is kinda lengthy so I'll just provide you the essentials:
// Start of the code
{
    "name": "Placeholder",
    "colors": {
        "editor.background": "#000000",
        "editor.foreground": "#ffffff",
        "activityBarBadge.background": "#007acc",
        "sideBarTitle.foreground": "#bbbbbb",
        "sideBar.background": "#111111"
    },
    "tokenColors": [

// The main problem:
        {
            "name": "Brackets and other stuff",
            "scope": [
                "punctuation.definition.group",
                "punctuation.definition.brackets"
            ],
            "settings": {
                "fontStyle": "bold",
                "foreground": "#006e25"
            }
        },

(don't mind the big tabs, stackoverflow added them)
I tried basically everything I could in the "scope" section.
"punctuation.definition.block",
"punctuation.section.braces",
"punctuation.definition.array",
"punctuation.section.parens"

"punctuation.definition.group",
"punctuation.definition.brackets"

"punctuation.section.braces"
"punctuation.section.brackets",
"punctuation.section.parens"

but it seems like the setting attached to it doesn't effect the parenthesis, brackets etc.

You should mention which language you are targeting.

You need to set "editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": true, and the following block in "settings.json" which colorizes (), {} and [] :
{
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "[One Dark Pro]": {  // the colorscheme I am using
            "editorBracketHighlight.foreground1": "#bdb2ff",
            "editorBracketHighlight.foreground2": "#80c4ff",
            "editorBracketHighlight.foreground3": "#acdcdd",
            "editorBracketHighlight.foreground4": "#baff8f",
            "editorBracketHighlight.foreground5": "#fdefb6",
            "editorBracketHighlight.foreground6": "#ff8dad",
        }
    }
}


